# OKHTTP, Dispatcher with a ProgressBar

Tags: java, okhttp

Simple Question, but I couldn't find any solution. I am using OKHTTP with a Dispatcher to mass-download files. What I like to have is a progress bar on all downloads.

Is there a way to extend OKHTTP's dispatcher to enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should take an example like https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java and extend it to understand the group of requests you are making via some shared state.